# JS functions calling observer

Tags: javascript, debugging, observer-pattern, console.log

I need to know which of javascript function is calling on any event happening in the application.
Is there any methodology or solution to implement that without placing the console. log/dir within every function?

---

UPD

My application uses mostly Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the issue is completely clear. If the problem is that all functions are anonymous (when an error is thrown, the console references 'anonymous function'), consider naming all functions as a standard.

```
var foo = function foo(params) {
    //things happen here
}
```

Rather than:

```
Var foo = function () {
    //things happen here
}
```

Also

```
btn.onclick = function btnClickHandler(e) {
    //btn clicked
}
```

The console will then refer to the function name when an error is thrown.